# Javascript: Get current GPS location using on{x} api?

Tags: javascript, android, api, location

I'm playing around with the on{x} api trying to create a rule that shows a notification of where you are (and maybe link it to open google maps?) everytime you park your car (when you go from driving to walking/standing still). I saw it in the demo video of on{x} but i didn't find the rule, so i figured i'd try making it myself, just for fun.

I'm having some issues getting the current gps coordinates though, i can't seem to figure out how to use the location api.

Here's what i've got so far:

```
device.modeOfTransport.on('changed', function(signal) {
    if (signal.previous === 'driving' && (signal.current === 'walking' || signal.current === 'atrest')) {

    }
});
```

If any javascript masters out there could take a look at the api it would be great. Here's the location api:

https://www.onx.ms/#apiPage/location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `modeOfTransport` `changed` handler does not feed you location information directly.  (Why?  Probably because `modeOfTransport` can be asserted from accelerometer telemetry only, so GPS isn't even involved.) You'll have to build and start a `locationListener` in your handler, and use the location information that is fed to that listener's handler.

For example, you might try the following (which I pieced together, more or less, from copy and pastes from the documentation).

```
device.modeOfTransport.on('changed', function(signal) {
    if (signal.previous === 'driving' && (signal.current === 'walking' || signal.current === 'atrest')) {
         var listener = device.location.createListener('GPS', 5000); 
         listener.on('changed', function (signal) {
            console.info('Lat: ' + signal.location.latitude);
            console.info('Lon: ' + signal.location.longitude);
            listener.stop();
         });
         listener.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: I figured it would have to be done somewhat like this, i just wasn't sure how to piece it together. I'm not sure exactly how it works though. The 5000 interval, is that irrelevant? Because the listener will be stopped the first time it runs anyway, right? Or will it wait 5 seconds before it starts? If so, setting it to 0 would be smarter right? Thank you!

Comment: @qwerty The documentation isn't completely clear on when the location handler is triggered, but yes - I would expect it to be invoked once, and then stopped.  Furthermore, I presume all of this is run in a single thread (since they seem to want to cater to web developers), which would also suggest that even if multiple events were queued to invoke your handler, they would be blocked and then ignored since you stop the listener after the first invocation.

Comment: Well alright then. I'm going for a drive! Thanks for the help!